# Conceptually(not technically), is ASP.Net Web API a subset of SignalR?

Tags: asp.net, rest, asp.net-web-api, signalr, comet

I know that Web API is for RESTful services and SignalR is for bidirectional(duplex) communication. 
But SignalR can be used as RESTful service as well.
What is the advantage of Web API over SignalR?

Answer (score 1):

This isn't an exhaustive answer, but the first thing that comes to mind is **simplicity**. SignalR requires some fairly complex ceremony to set up, especially when dealing with server farms. Web API is far more straightforward, both to understand as a developer and to operate.